# How to remove commas from web element text in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to remove `,` from WebElement?

Details:

I scraped a web page using selenium but from that text I want to remove `,`

For Example:

If I **scrape** `hey, welcome 2020` before this will enter on my csv file I want to remove `,`

Here is my code:

```
if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__addressLink--1pLK4 ._2wKz--mA .restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei')):
    address = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__addressLink--1pLK4 ._2wKz--mA .restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei')

else:
    address = 'NONE'

with open(save,'a',encoding='utf-8') as s:
    for i in range(1):
        addresst = address

        if addresst == 'NONE':
            addresst = str(address)
        else:
            addresst = address[i].text

        s.write(addresst + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `replace(',', '')`? you also don't need to locate the elements twice

```
address = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__addressLink--1pLK4 ._2wKz--mA .restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei')
with open(save,'a',encoding='utf-8') as s:
    if address:
        addresst = address[0].texts.replace(',', '')
    else:
        addresst = 'NONE'

    s.write(addresst + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

If want to write the web element text value in CSV without having  "," in it. You Can use below code.

```
if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.restaurants-detail-overview-cards- 
    LocationOverviewCard__addressLink--1pLK4 ._2wKz--mA .restaurants-detail-overview- 
    cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei')):
             address = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.restaurants-detail- 
             overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__addressLink--1pLK4 ._2wKz-- 
             mA.restaurants-detail-overview-cards-              
             LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei')

else:
    address = 'NONE'
with open(save,'a',encoding='utf-8') as s:
    for i in range(1):
        addresst = address

       if addresst == 'NONE':
           addresst = str(address)
       else:
           addresst = address[i].text.replace(',','')

       s.write(addresst + '\n')
```